# Polynomial evaluation in haskell

Tags: haskell, polynomial-math

I've been trying to make a function which evaluates polynomials of integers.

Now I have

```
> type Poly = [Int]

> polyEval :: [(Float,Int)] -> Float -> [(Float,Int)]
> polyEval [] _ = []
> polyEval ((c,g):xs) n = map (\ (c,g) -> (c*n,g)) xs
```

If I put in `polyEval [] 3` the output is `[]`. But when I want to calculate something like `polyEval [3] 2`, Hugs says

```
ERROR - Cannot infer instance
*** Instance   : Num (Float,Int)
*** Expression : polyEval [3] 2
```

Why?

Comment: Do you can describe you algorithm verbose?

Comment: What are you trying to do with `polyEval`?  The name (and your question) suggests you want to evaluate the polynomial;  why does it return a list?

Answer (score 3):

You promise to compiler put list of tuples `(Float, Int)` to `polyEval` function, but you put only `3`. 
Haskell try cast 3 to (Float, Int), but it is impossible. If you call polyEval as `polyEval [(1.0, 3)] 2` it will compile fine.

Another point - you make pattern matching on head of the list `polyEval ((c,g):xs)` and drop results in following computations.

Comment: Thanks! Now my output is always []. Where's the faullt

Comment: @haskellnoob you always drop first element of list and then map the rest. If you have list with single element - you map empty list and result is empty list too.

Comment: Note that we avoid to speak of "casting number literals to...". Haskell never does implicit casts. A better way to describe it, IMO, is "Haskell tries to interpret `3` as a `(Float, Int)` value".

Comment: @leftaroundabout i agree with you. i will use this description